# Converting from Java String to Windows-1252 Format

Tags: java, android, encoding

I want to send a URL request, but the parameter values in the URL can have french characters (eg. è). How do I convert from a Java String to Windows-1252 format (which supports the French characters)?

I am currently doing this:

`String encodedURL = new String (unencodedUrl.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Windows-1252");`

However, it makes: 
`param=Stationnement extèrieur` into `param=Stationnement extÃ©rieur` .

How do I fix this? Any suggestions?

Edit for further clarification:

The user chooses values from a drop down. When the language is French, the values from the drop down sometimes include French characters, like 'è'. When I send this request to the server, it fails, saying it is unable to decipher the request. I have to figure out how to send the 'è' as a different format (preferably Windows-1252) that supports French characters. I have chosen to send as Windows-1252. The server will accept this format. I don't want to replace each character, because I could miss a special character, and then the server will throw an exception.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. At all. Maybe you want to [percent-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the query parameters?

Comment: Maybe you might need to explain what are you trying to do because if you are trying to sending a request with those values it make sense to make the URL encoding as @Matt Ball has explained.

Comment: I have added more information about my problem now. Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [URLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode parameter values as *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* data:

```
 String param = "param="
              + URLEncoder.encode("Stationnement extr\u00e8ieur", "cp1252");
```

See [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/12/java-safe-character-handling-and-url.html) for an expanded explanation.

Comment: I would have to replace the special e character with \u00e8 before passing it to be converted to cp1252. Doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: The Unicode escape sequence `\u00e8` is just an alternative way to write è in String literals to avoid [compiler encoding issues](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_sourcefiles).

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
String encodedURL = new String (unencodedUrl.getBytes("UTF-8"), Charset.forName("Windows-1252"));
```

Comment: I get the following error:

`The constructor (byte[], Charsest) is undefined`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo * `The constructor (byte[], Charset) is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

As per McDowell's suggestion, I tried encoding doing:

`URLEncoder.encode("stringValueWithFrechCharacters", "cp1252")` but it didn't work perfectly. I replayced `"cp1252"` with `HTTP.ISO_8859_1` because I believe Android does not have the support for Windows-1252 yet. It does allow for ISO_8859_1, and after reading [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), this supports MOST of the French characters, with the exception of 'Œ', 'œ', and 'Ÿ'.

So doing this made it work:

```
URLEncoder.encode(frenchString, HTTP.ISO_8859_1);
```

Works perfectly!